sysfs error when trying to change frequency
I am encountering this error when trying to change the frequency of PWM:
2024-01-14 01:22:19,413 - INFO - Server is waiting for a connection...
2024-01-14 01:22:28,075 - INFO - Connected to ('192.168.6.1', 45346)
2024-01-14 01:22:35,921 - INFO - Received command: MF5
2024-01-14 01:22:35,924 - DEBUG - Running motors with freq: 2000, direction: forward
2024-01-14 01:22:35,926 - DEBUG - Stopping any existing PWM instances
2024-01-14 01:22:35,928 - DEBUG - Waiting for hardware to reset
2024-01-14 01:22:36,030 - DEBUG - Setting direction to: forward
2024-01-14 01:22:36,033 - DEBUG - Starting PWM on pins P8_13 and P8_19 with frequency 2000
2024-01-14 01:22:36,292 - ERROR - Attempt 1 failed: Problem with a sysfs file
2024-01-14 01:22:36,397 - DEBUG - Starting PWM on pins P8_13 and P8_19 with frequency 2000
2024-01-14 01:22:36,413 - ERROR - Attempt 2 failed: Problem with a sysfs file
2024-01-14 01:22:36,516 - DEBUG - Starting PWM on pins P8_13 and P8_19 with frequency 2000
2024-01-14 01:22:36,530 - ERROR - Attempt 3 failed: Problem with a sysfs file
2024-01-14 01:22:36,635 - ERROR - Failed to start PWM after 3 attempts
2024-01-14 01:22:36,638 - INFO - Client disconnected

I can't get the hang of it, how to troubleshoot this.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to make it answerable. Please tell us more details about your project, hardware, OS, schematic. Since you have tagged it with "Python", please add your Python source code, reduced to a [mre].

problem with a sysfs file is way poorly written error message. Without code and actual listings from shell from the same system it's impossible to tell anything, moreover, debugging is an offtopic here.
